# How can i move the chromium buttons to the left in KDE4?

Tags: linux, kde-4, gtk, chromium, qt

Can I make like this :

[image: this sample image is from gnome]

Under KDE4?  How?

Answer (score 0):

Chromium does not use the KDE windows decorator. Therefore, this configuration must be made in chromium, or if not as option available in the source code of chromium. Probably using a different theme might help.

Answer (score 0):

Does KDE4 have left side buttons?

If so does "Settings > Options > Personal Stuff > Use System Title Bars" not work.

Sorry that I obviously don't have KDE4 but want to mention this setting in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to use system title bars, as you see it's native on left.